# Clear values from a range that does not specify the total number of rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to clear the values of the `Clima!V1:V` range, but it's giving an **error** because I don't specify the total size of the range, *what is the simplest way to solve this problem?* Taking into account that the total amount of rows in this column can change according to the time.

```
function ApagarHistoricoDoClima() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange('Clima!V1:V').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reccomend using the `Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows)` function from the Spreadsheets library. So, I would use the following code:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Clima');
const range = sheet.getRange(1, 22, sheet.getMaxRows());
range.clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
```

`getMaxRows` is a function documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows).

### EDIT:

Per the request by the question poster, I have made a simplified version of this script, more easily accessable to a person with less programming experience:

```
// USER: START EDITING HERE

const sheetName = 'Clima';
const column = 'V';
const startRow = 1;

// USER: DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
const lastRow = sheet.getMaxRows();
const range = sheet.getRange(column + startRow + ':' + column + lastRow);
range.clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
```

As is shown in the code, the user should only edit the three constants, and then does not have to worry about the below. If you did not want `startRow` to be something that can be modified, you could move that below the user variables. I will leave it to you to explain to end users how to modify the three variables.

Also, per the second answer to this question, you can use `getLastRow` instead of `getMaxRows` in the script. `getLastRow` gets the last row with content in the sheet, whereas `getMaxRows` gets the actual last row in the entire sheet.

Comment: Hello my friend, I'm leaving this script for use by people who don't have any knowledge in scripting, for them it would be easier if you had to select the range according to the specific names like ```Clima!V1:V```, is there any option? If it doesn't exist, I already put your answer as the solution, if it does, could you add the answer please?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @BrondbyIF! Do the edits I made help? If so, would be great if you could accept this solution (click the check mark on the left side of the answer) in addition to the upvote. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
const range = sheet.getRange(1, 22, sheet.getLastRow());
```

Comment: @thedp: While it's advised that answers contain an explanation—and often worth encouraging contributors to do so—it's not a reason to vote to _delete_ an answer ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)).